# Arrange Fields display in Drupal 7 with CSS

Tags: css, drupal, html, field

I have a Problem with displaying Fields in Drupal 7 .

I have 3 Fields and want show two of them on a Firs row and show another one on second row Exactly under second Field in a first row .

its about 3 Hours that i searching and cant find a Solution :(

this a Screenshot :

http://i45.tinypic.com/12190l1.jpg

My Field's displays like Number 1 , but i want to display them like Number 2 .
and Number Field maybe have more than 4 digits . so i can't using Margins :(

How can i Fix this ?

Thanks a lot .

Answer (score 0):

You could use a tabular layout within the content div. Here is a an [example](http://jsfiddle.net/bKWLf/) to get you started. You would obviously remove the border and add some spacing but you can find more info on that [here](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_tables.asp).

```
<div class="content">
 <table border="1">
  <tr>
   <td>1234</td>
   <td colspan="2">Heading</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <td ></td>
   <td colspan="2">Info</td>
  </tr>
 </table>​
</div>
```

Comment: so , The question is : how can i use Tables in Drupal Fields ?

Comment: Use css or override the node theme (node.tpl.php).
Do a google search for drupal theming for more info

Comment: Thanks guys , it was Solved :)